# Importing and using a function that takes argparse as a parameter

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to import a program and use a couple functions in it, but I'm running into an issue pertaining to argparse.

In the functions I would like to use, the creator passes his parser args to the function like so.

```
args = parser.parse_args()

def write_flash(esp, args):

    if args.compress is None and not args.no_compress:
    args.compress = not args.no_stub

    # verify file sizes fit in flash
    flash_end = flash_size_bytes(args.flash_size)
    for address, argfile in args.addr_filename:
        argfile.seek(0,2)  # seek to end
        if address + argfile.tell() > flash_end:
```

I'm wondering how I can use this function in another program I'm writing.  Do I somehow create a parser.parse_args() object with the same arguments as him?  One thing I thought of is using subprocess.popen to run it like so:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'esptool.py', '--port',
'COM3', 'write_flash', '0x00000', 'boot_v1.7.bin', '0xfc000', 'esp_init_data_    default_v08.bin', '0xfb000',
'blank.bin', '0x01000', 'user1.1024.new.2.bin'])
```

But this seems less than ideal.  I'm really lost in general on how to approach argparse in general and any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can `from fileyouposted import args` and you'll have whatever args got parsed. Also note that the raw cli arguments are always available in `sys.argv`.

Comment: `args` can be any object that has attributes like `args.compress`. `argparse.Namespace` is a convenient way of creating such an object, but it could be almost any class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_args()` returns a [`Namespace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace) object. You can just create one yourself.

```
from argparse import Namespace`
args = Namespace()
args.compress = True
args.no_stub = 3
print(args)
```

and then pass it.

Comment: or `Namespace(compress=True, no_stub=3)`